# Finding highest / lowest position

Tags: c#, lambda, conditional-statements, coordinates, minmax

I have coordinate system, where I need to find: lowest X, highest X, lowest Y and highest Y position.
There is also rotation, which is needed to check also, rotations are '0' or '90'. These X and Y points is at middle of my thing, so i need to calculate it to the edge of this.
I tried lambda with condition statement eg.

```
double yMin = myCoords.coord.Min(i => i.Position.Rot == 0 ? i.Position.Y - this.thingy.Where(k => k.name == i.name).First().Length / 2) : i.Position.Y - this.thingy.Where(k => k.name == i.name).First().Width / 2)
```

But this doesn't seems like its giving it right, result are way too low or way too high than its possible.
Am I doing something wrong here?